# Libre Office menu does not show submenus automatically

Tags: libreoffice, appmenu

I've just update my libreoffice 4.0.2.2 to 4.0.3.3....  When I start Writer, Impress or Calc, the first time I click on any main menu it does not show submenus automatically (I recorded problem using RecordMyDesktop and uploaded to the following [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNQ0r4YVITU).
I heard that menu issues are realted to Unity. So is it Ubuntu or LibreOffice problem? And any idea how to fix it?

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and Libre Office 4.0.3.3. (this didn't happen in 4.0.2.2.)..

Comment: How did you install Libre Office 4.0.3.3 ?

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0
and then went to Software Updater...

Comment: I suggest you file a bug report. http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug You may get a bit of a run around, but the two should work together.

Comment: I reported the bug to libre office, and it is now classifed as RESOLVED WONTFIX https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=64565

Comment: Hate it when they do that , I feel your pain. Perhaps file with Ubuntu, but again, if it is in a ppa it is likely considered experimental. Perhaps message to persone who packaged the .deb

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by itself. I installed Libre Office 4.0.3.3. from official Libre Office PPA when problem appeared, but today Ubuntu Software Center found updates (!!!) and updated it to the same version I've already have (4.0.3.3).

After this, Libre Office shows submenus automatically, no delay...

I guess, installing software from other sources (such as Libre Office PPA) could cause such problems and it is better to wait for official Ubuntu updates.

Comment: Just [got the news](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/17839/drop-down-menu-not-visible-in-lo-writer-calc/?answer=17905#post-id-17905) that [the bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63840) in PPA packages for 12.04 has been fixed.